# How to get notifications between Poise LWRP in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I'm attempting to learn more about LWRP's and have a working provider that installs a package. I am stuck trying to notify my service when configuration changes - basically I have this below.

Can I make the runit service subscribe to notifications that the package has installed/config changed ? In the solution is it possible to decouple service and package ie. observer based rather than notifies runit_service["abc"] ? I thought of creating a separate provider for the service but have not found clear examples yet.

```
module MyApp

  class Resource < Chef::Resource
         include Poise
         provides(:my_app)
         actions(:enable)
  end

  class Provider < Chef::Provider
        include Poise
        provides(:my_app)

        def action_enable 
           notifying_block do

             template new_resource.database_config do 
                source 'database.erb'
                #how to notify runit?
             end

             deploy_revision new_resource.process_id do
                #how to notify runit?
             end
           end
        end
   end
end
```

and in the recipe

```
my_app 'one' do
  #some attributes
  process_user 'nobody'
  process_group 'nogroup'

end


runit_service "myapp" do
  cookbook "myapp" 
  run_template_name "myapp"
  log_template_name "myapp"
  options({
    :app_env => "development",
    :app_home => "/srv/myapp/current",
    :data_dir => "/srv/myapp/data"
  })
  retries 3
  retry_delay 5
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: I should have left Poise out of the title - happy for non-poise solutions too.

Comment: The poise author doesn't normally watch this anymore, but he may have particular interest in this one.

Comment: The answer is totally different depending on whether you use poise or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not notify from or to resources inside LWRPs.

Depending on the chef version and the value of `use_inline_resources` you can't notify as the resources inside the LWRP are converged in a separate context.

However if one the resources inside the LWRP has been updated, the LWRP will be marked as updated and can notify a resource.

You may have a [notification](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifies-syntax) to restart the service from your `my_app resource` like this:

```
my_app 'one' do
  #some attributes
  process_user 'nobody'
  process_group 'nogroup'
  notifies :restart,"runit_service[myapp]" # adapt action and may use timer :immediately, see the doc link above 
end
```

Or if you wish to work the other way you can use the [subscribe](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#subscribes-syntax) way like this:

```
runit_service "myapp" do
  cookbook "myapp" 
  run_template_name "myapp"
  log_template_name "myapp"
  options({
    :app_env => "development",
    :app_home => "/srv/myapp/current",
    :data_dir => "/srv/myapp/data"
  })
  retries 3
  retry_delay 5
  subscribes :restart,"my_app[one]" # again adapt action and may use timer :immediately, see the doc link above
end
```

Usually the subscribe syntax is usefull to avoid notifications in each other resource, there can be many, so if your service host multiples apps, it could be easiest to get it will restart on each app change with multiples subscribes lines in the service than a notification in each app.

I.e:

```
runit_service "tomcat" do 
  [...]
  subscribe :restart,"my_app[one]"
  subscribe :restart,"my_app[two]"
  subscribe :restart,"my_app[three]"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## For Poise

According to [the poise documentation](https://github.com/poise/poise#notifying-block) You can notify any resource, even those outside the resource action.  Poise will search for a matching resource up the sub-contexts until it finds a match.  So you can do a `notifies` on your `template` or `deploy_revision` resources that will notify your `runit_service`.

Furthermore, the `notifying_block` acts similar to the `use_inline_resources` in a normal LWRP.  So if your `runit_service` subscribes to the `my_app` resource, it will get notified if *either* the `deploy_revision` or `template` is updated.

This is the power of MWRP (middle weight resource providers, aka poise).  It let's you do things you can't do in a normal LWRP.  As Tensibai explained in his answer, if you are not using poise, you can't notify outside of the provider's own resource stack.